# selectedIndex attribute of panelTabbedPane in JSF not working

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

JSP code

```
<t:panelTabbedPane align="left"  serverSideTabSwitch="false" styleClass="tabbedPane" 
            activeTabStyleClass="activeTab" inactiveTabStyleClass="inactiveTab" width="100%" cellpadding="0"
            cellspacing="0" tabContentStyleClass="tabContent" style="margin-top:0px;text-align:center"
            selectedIndex="#{myBB.selectedTab}">
```

/***************************************************************************/

Backing Bean Code:

```
private int selectedIndex;



    public int getSelectedIndex() {
        System.out.println("getter of selectedIndexis called "+selectedIndex);
        return selectedIndex;
    }

    public void setSelectedIndex(int selectedIndex) {
        System.out.println("Setter of selectedIndexis called "+selectedIndex);
        this.selectedIndex= selectedIndex;
    }
```

The backing bean is of session scope.
When i change panelTab in the screen and click on submit button, always the default panel is being shown. I checked the console to find the sysout from setter of selectedIndex.But in console it is not being printed which means(I suppose) the selectedIndex is not being posted to the server.I'm using JSF version 1.1. Can any one suggest how to make this work ?

Comment: System.out.println("Request map "+FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap());
    System.out.println("Request Param map "+FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()); I tried this to find whether selectedIndex is getting posted to the server.Even in this also there is no such param.

Comment: is your `t:panelTabbedPane ` inside a `h:form`? place the submit button method inside that bean and try to `System.out.println(selectedIndex);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537369/jsf-otabbedpane-issue-changing-selectedindex

Comment: @Daniel Yes, both the t:panelTabbedPane and the submit button are in the same form.Also there is a single form in the whole page

Comment: what about the `System.out.println(selectedIndex);` what is being printed ?

Comment: @Daniel selectedIndex is coming as 0,the default value.

Comment: do you have nested forms on your page ? a form that wraps the `t:panelTabbedPane` and form/s inside the `t:panelTabbedPane` ?

Comment: @Daniel No, I dont have any nested form/s inside my complete page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_panelTabbedPane.html), `selectedIndex` is the default tab index to use, not the actual currently selected tab index.

Having said that, you can use a [`<t:tabChangeListener>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_tabChangeListener.html) to pick up the currently selected tab.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that may come across this:

You need to set serverSideTabSwitch="true" and use a tabChangeListener, or else the tab switches (and the known tab index) is entirely done in the client.